# React-router <Link> doesn't work with react 16.8 correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

Have a problem with react-router 5.0.0 and react 16.8

With **NavLink** app works as *expected* but with **Link** i got an error as

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgVwX.png)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import { Content } from '../../components/content/Content';

export class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Content>
        <Link to="/">Home Page</Link>
      </Content>
    );
  }
}
```

[SOLVED] I don't restart the app when converting functional component into class. The first one doesn't have `history` prop provided by `Router`

Comment: Where is the code from where you import the Home component?

Comment: you should import Home like this
`import Home from './Home.jsx` because its a default export

Comment: ^ wrong advice above

Comment: @jdc91 what do you mean ?

Comment: Show me where you import the Home component.

Comment: I have named export for <Content>

Comment: @Colin attached screenshot

Comment: You showed where the Home component is used, *not* where it's imported.

Comment: It is not import issue

Comment: because... with NavLink app works as expected but with Link i got an error

Answer (score 1):

From the error message:

> you might have mixed up default and named imports

You should be mixing the import statement. Follow the below convention to resolve your issue:

```
import Content from '...';
// for a default export
```

Rather than a named export:

```
import { Content } from '...'
// for a named export
```

See these reference to understand the named export and default export: [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import) and [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)

Comment: I tried to convert my component into class component and wrap into withRouter HOC
app still work if i change Link with NavLink

Comment: @MaxDvoynishnikov tyou have to import your wrapped component, in the way mentioned above.
instead of `import { Home} from '../../components/Home';` you have to use `import Home from '../../components/Home';`

Answer (score 0):

Wrong import statement.

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/Link.md

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

<Link to="/about">About</Link>
```

Comment: What? OP imported like this.